# Optimize VBA script to convert thousands of time values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have thousands of timestamped rows of Excel data but Excel doesn't recognize the times. The only way to get the times to be recognized is to click on a cell, hit F2 to edit, then hit enter. I wrote a script that automates that, but it takes a very long time to run (about 5min for ~6000 rows). Any thoughts on how to make this run more efficiently? Thanks!

This script works fine, but it's sloooooow. Please help! I tried dimming mycell as integer but that didn't help.

```
Sub EditColumnC()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim mycell As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Set the worksheet you want to work with
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'get # of rows
    With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    MsgBox lastrow & " vehicles detected"
    
    ' Loop through each cell in Column C
    For Each cell In ws.Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
        ' Edit the cell value while keeping the existing value
        mycell = cell.Value
        
        cell.Value = mycell 
        
      'reset mycell 
        mycell = 0
     
    Next cell
    
    MsgBox "Done!"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `With ws.Range("C1:C" & LastRow): .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss": .Value = .Value: End With`.

Comment: You can also use `Text to Columns`, I hope. You didn't tell the reason why your Excel didn't recognize your time data.

Comment: With ws.Range("C1:C" & LastRow): .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss": .Value = .Value: End With

Comment: It worked! Glory is mine! Thank you so much. Now it takes less than a second.